# c++ optional(T) -> optional<T>

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, option-type

I am reading std::optional in the page 539 of the draft [n4791](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4791.pdf).

I notice that there is a

```
template<class T>
optional(T) -> optional<T>;
```

What is the meaning of this statement?

How does it affect std::optional?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's a deduction guide. It allows statements like this:

```
std::optional o(42);  // o has type std::optional<int>
```